# Access phone camera using opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to connect my phone camera using IP webcam application but I get when error when I run the code.

Also, the URL keeps changing. Is there a method so that I don't need to change the URL every time?

This is the code I am using:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("http://192.168.43.1:8080/shot.jpg")
while True:        
    ret, frame = cap.read()  
    cv2.imshow("IPWebcam", cv2.resize(frame, (600, 400)))

    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

And this is the error message I get when I run it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\phone_cam.py", line 15, in <module>
    cv2.imshow("IPWebcam", cv2.resize(frame, (600, 400)))
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-9gpsewph\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:3929: error: 

(-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'
```

Comment: did you check what you read? e.g., frame.shape is not empty?

Comment: nope, but ret return false so it's not reading the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import cv2
import urllib.request
import numpy as np

URL = "http://192.168.43.1:8080/shot.jpg"


while(True):

    img_arr = np.array(
        bytearray(urllib.request.urlopen(URL).read()), dtype=np.uint8)
    frame = cv2.imdecode(img_arr, -1)

    # Display the image
    cv2.imshow('IPWebcam', cv2.resize(frame, (1100, 800)))

    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cv2.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer will not directly solve the issue, but it will allow you to detect the cause and it's a good practice when reading a video, image or from a camera. Always check if the value of `ret` is `True` because if it is not, it means there was a problem reading the data.

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("http://192.168.43.1:8080/shot.jpg")
while True:        
    ret, frame = cap.read()  
    if ret:
        cv2.imshow("IPWebcam", cv2.resize(frame, (600, 400)))

        if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        print("cap.read() returned False")
```

If the code prints the message in the else statement, that means there is an issue with the link. Check if it is the correct one and whether you need to add a username and password or not.

Comment: it return false, i tried another method which work but i saw some stack post that they suggest this method so i tried this method